# PC doesn't open any OS, error unknown file system , rescue mode

Tags: boot, grubrescue

I write commands for grub rescue, but it also shows this error.

[image]

Comment: Try to get hold of some alternative boot media (liveCD, liveUSB, ...) and examine the situation/recover from there.

Comment: You need to specify a root partition, not just boot, and you need to insmod a filesystem like ext3/4.